# How to display data that was saved in android

Tags: android, list, file, save, android-sdcard

I am working on a project in which I am saving data in a class with a filename and data attached to a folder on the sdcard. I need another class to display a list of all the filenames and when you click on them it opens the saved data (text) in an editor or something. I am somewhat new to android, sorry if I am missing something obvious here.

So basically I need to display the file names of data that I have saved in a list view and when you click on them, it takes the data and sends it (Probably using shared prefs or BroadcastReceiver) to a class where you can edit it. I could also use a database if that would be easier.

Comment: Can you provide an example and/or show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See **First** way is to make variable as **static**  so you can access by class name.
**second** Use **file** for data storage it is easy to create file.
**third** is use **Share preference** i.e.mobile seeting
**fourth** you can use SQlite to store data.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to store the required data:

- Shared Preference (If the data is lesser say for example login
  creadentials etc).

  - Internal\External Storage (we can store data images,files etc .Your sd card case is of external storage)
  - Database (SQL Lite is present and stores structured data in a private database.)

Study the link for storage options.Choose the best options as per requirement and need.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html